# Как убрать названия улиц с гугл maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

У гугл карты АПИ есть свойство styles куда передаётся массив с объектами свойств. Есть ли такое свойство убирающее названия улиц с карты? помогите найти.

Answer (score 1):

Есть стилизатор карт: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

В нём Roads -> Text > Hidden

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]